# Invalid bucket name on circle-ci(Deploy to AWS S3 )

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront, circleci

**situation**

- I did success build on circle-ci and I tried deploying to AWS S3 but
  something problem  occurs

**Goal**

- Build on ciecle-ci →AWS S3 → AWS cloudfront

this is my [repo](https://github.com/taiga-programming/cinema-app/blob/develop/.circleci/config.yml)

**error**

```
!/bin/bash -eo pipefail
if ["${develop}"=="master"]
then
  aws --region ${AWS_REGION} s3 sync ~/repo/build s3://{AWS_BUCKET_PRODUCTION} --delete
elif  ["${develop}" == "staging"]
then
  aws --region ${AWS_REGION} s3 sync ~/repo/build s3://{AWS_BUCKET_STAGING} --delete
else
  aws --region ${AWS_REGION} s3 sync ~/repo/build s3://{AWS_BUCKET_DEV} --delete
fi
/bin/bash: [==master]: command not found
/bin/bash: line 3: [: missing `]'
fatal error: Parameter validation failed:
Invalid bucket name "{AWS_BUCKET_DEV}": Bucket name must match the regex "^[a-zA-Z0-9.\-_]{1,255}$"
```

**Variable name**

- AWS_BUCKET_PRODUCTION
- AWS_BUCKET_STAGING
- AWS_DEV_BUCKET

I used this site for checking my name

https://regex101.com/r/2IFv8B/1

Answer (score 1):

You need to put a `$` in front of `{AWS_BUCKET_DEV}`, `{AWS_BUCKET_STAGING}`, and `{AWS_BUCKET_PRODUCTION}` respectively. Otherwise the shell doesn’t replace the variable names with their values.

```
... s3://${AWS_BUCKET_DEV} ...
```